# Definition of "Standard Coordinates" in Tu's Introduction to Manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, smooth-manifolds, coordinate-systems

Reading through [Introduction to Manifolds](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiO2Ma29dTmAhUcQEEAHdUUCegQFjAIegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1HVAMX2LD18O9yw_7061_N), and quite often the term "Standard Coordinates" appears.

In Linear Algebra these are usually the weights of the standard basis (such weights are denoted by $r^1,\ldots,r^n$. However as soon as we get to smooth manifolds these seems to denote some functions. Suppose we have a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ with some chart $(U,\phi) = (U,x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ centered around $p \in M$. The standard coordinates seem to be functions such that $x^i = r^i \circ \phi$, which to me this would translate in the projection operator. Can anyone clarify what the meaning of standard coordinates is in this context? It's really hard to work out the details of the proofs sometimes because of this subtle detail.

Comment: Would you provide a passage where this term is appear ?

Comment: The 'weights' that you talk about are the values of the coordinates of a specific point $p$. As the point changes you get functions that input a point and output the corresponding $i$-th weight. These are the standard coordinate functions. If it make it more clear append the name 'function' and remove it when talking about their values at a point.

Comment: I guess it means $\Bbb{R}^n$ with standard basis $e_i = (0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0).$ So $x = \sum_{i=1}^n x^ie_i = (x^1,\dots,x^n)$ means $x^i$ is the i-th coefficient wrt this basis.

Comment: @Sou just to a quick search for "Standard Coordinates" through the I linked. But the first time it appears is in the abstract of chapter 1 (Euclidean Spaces).

Comment: "Euclidean space is special in having a set of standard global coordinates.  This is both a blessing and a handicap.  It is a blessing because all constructions on $\mathbb R^n$
can be defined in terms of the standard coordinates... Since a manifold in general does not have standard coordinates..." So this does not refer to other smooth manifolds, and the expression is only applied to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I still can't figure a definition that would be applicable in the context of the book.

Comment: The definition is that the standard coordinate (functions) are $x^k:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ (with the notation in that book of using superscripts) defined by $x^k(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=a_k$.

Comment: @user8469759 What is your conclusion in this regard?

Comment: @rainman My conclusion is that the standard is the function that returns the specific coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's a lot of abuse of notation in differential geometry, so "standard coordinates" may have different meanings in different contexts. This is the first paragraph of Tu where I found the expression:

"*The Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the prototype of all manifolds. Not only is it the simplest,
but locally every manifold looks like $\mathbb{R}^n$. A good understanding of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is essential in
generalizing differential and integral calculus to a manifold.
Euclidean space is special in having a set of standard global coordinates.*"

This is what I understood from the paragraph:

Considering $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a manifold, you can give $\mathbb{R}^n$ the following smooth structure (which is usually called the standard structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$) with the following atlas, consisting on a single chart (this is what I think Tu means by "global"):

$$\{U, \varphi\}=\{\mathbb{R}^n, \text{Id}_\mathbb{{R}^n}\}$$

This chart provides you with an homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ regarded as a manifold and the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, and its coordinates will be:

\begin{array}{cccl}
\varphi \equiv (x^1,...,x^n): &U &\longrightarrow &\mathbb{R}^n
\\\ &p &\longmapsto & (x^1(p),...,x^n(p)) = (p_1,...,p_n)
\end{array}

So these "standard coordinates" will map a point $p$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ considered as a manifold to the same point $p$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ considered as a vector space.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I'm bringing this up again. Could you tell me if my understanding is correct? If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then given the canonical basis $\left\{e_1,\ldots, e_n \right\}$ we have $$x = x^1 e_1 + \ldots x^n e_n $$ and to me the standard coordinates are functions $r^i : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^i = r^i(e_i)$. In the case of a manifold we have some chart $\varphi : U \subset M \to \mathbb{R}^n$, hence $\varphi(p) = x^1(p) e_1 + \ldots x^n(p) e_n$ and therefore $x^i(p) = r^i(\varphi(p)) = (r^i \circ \varphi)(p)$.

Comment: Therefore when Tu says $r^1,\ldots,r^n$ are the standard coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$ I understand it as the functionals that given a vector will return the corresponding coordinate. Is this right? (I'm asking again for future reference).

Comment: @user8469759 Beautifully clarified. Your comments make sense to me.